# Parse binary tree from file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have task to write Quiz Animal game. I have to read Tree data from file (the structure of file is free). After end of game is possible to be added new data in tree(actually (Animal) to be replace by (Node (Animal) (Animal)).

My problem is that i can't parse content of "database.txt" in AnimalsTree

Example "database.txt" (this content is generated with writing before call 'New Game'):

> Question "Is it fly?" (Animal "Bird") (Question "Is it swim?" (Animal "Fish") (Animal "Dog"))

**EDIT**
This is full code:

```
module Main where
import System.IO
data AnimalsTree = Animal String | Question String AnimalsTree AnimalsTree deriving (Read, Show)
-- Видовете отговори на потребителя
data Answer = Yes | No

main :: IO ()
main = do root <- "database.txt"
          play (read root)
          return ()

play :: AnimalsTree -> IO AnimalsTree
play root = do putStrLn "Think of an animal, I will try to guess what it is..."
               newRoot <- play' root
               writeFile "database.txt" (show newRoot)
               playAgain <- ask "Do you want to play again?"
               case playAgain of
                   Yes -> play newRoot
                   No  -> do putStrLn "Bye!"
                             return newRoot

play' :: AnimalsTree -> IO AnimalsTree
play' question@(Question q l r) = do ans <- ask q
                                     case ans of
                                        Yes -> do y <- play' l
                                                  return $ Question q y r
                                        No  -> do n <- play' r
                                                  return $ Question q l n

play' animal@(Animal _) = do ans <- ask $ "Are you thinking of " ++ show' animal ++ "?"
                             case ans of
                                Yes -> do putStrLn "I win! :)"
                                          return animal
                                No  -> do putStrLn "I give up, you win!"
                                          getNewAnimal animal


getNewAnimal :: AnimalsTree -> IO AnimalsTree
getNewAnimal animal = do putStrLn "Please help me!"
                         putStrLn "What is name of yout animal?"
                         name <- getLine
                         let newAnimal = Animal name
                         putStrLn $ "Now please enter a question that answers yes for " ++ show' newAnimal ++ " and no for " ++ show' animal
                         question <- getLine
                         return $ Question question newAnimal animal

ask :: String -> IO Answer
ask s = do putStrLn $ s ++ " (Yes/No)"
           getAnswer

getAnswer :: IO Answer
getAnswer = do ans <- getLine
               putStrLn ""
               case ans of
                   "y" -> return Yes
                   "Y" -> return Yes
                   "yes" -> return Yes
                   "Yes" -> return Yes
                   "n" -> return No
                   "N" -> return No
                   "no" -> return No
                   "No" -> return No
                   _   -> putStrLn "This is incorect answer! Please try again with value in 'Yes' or 'No'!" >> getAnswer

show' (Animal name) = (if elem (head name) "AEIOUaeiou" then "an " else "a ") ++ name
show' (Question q _ _) = q
```

But I get following error:

```
test3.hs:10:19:
    No instance for (Read (IO AnimalsTree))
      arising from a use of ‘read’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: root <- read "database.txt"
    In the expression:
      do { root <- read "database.txt";
           play (root);
           return () }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = do { root <- read "database.txt";
                 play (root);
                 return () }
```

Comment: You've already derived `Read`. Doesn't that give you a parser for free? Or, more to the point: What did you try, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: I edit my post!

Comment: You cannot return a pure value from the `main` function. Also, `return` is not the `return` from languages like C or Java, it's a function from a type class called `Monad`, a very powerful tool of abstraction.

Comment: Furthermore, looking at your code, you write `animals :: [Tree] = fileString`, which is syntactically incorrect, but you never use the value `animals` anywhere is your code.

Comment: Ok,thank you! `animals :: [Tree] = fileString` is incorect. How can i cast read content to Tree and print it in console?

Comment: I put all code in post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a great start! I only needed to add `readFile` to your `main` function to get it to compile:

```
main = do root <- readFile "database.txt"
```

It is possible that you may need to switch from `readFile` to explicitly opening the file for reading, doing the reading, and closing the file. This is because `readFile` does not guarantee when it will close the file, and `writeFile` is allowed to fail if it is given a path to a file that's already open.

You can read the documentation for `openFile`, `hGetLine`, and `hClose` for further details on how to do this (but beware `hGetContents`, as it has the same caveats `readFile` does).

Comment: You are hero! Thank you! Just save my life! ^.^